# Unity Transform Speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    wall.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 5 , 0);
}
```

I want the 'wall' game object to move at a specific speed instead of moving instantly, what's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want, one of them using [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) method.

```
void Update()
{
   float speed = 2;
   // Move the object upward in world space 1 unit/second * speed.
   wall.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnTriggerEnter will be only called once when Collider will be triggered. what you can do is set boolean "true" on OnTriggerEnter and then Update position in update when that boolean is "true". and then set is to false once you have done your update.

There are 2-3 other ways to do this, You can also use doTween to do this, but according to your question I think you are beginner so above will be easy to implemetn according to me.